# ASP.NET Core MVC controller to calling ASP.NET Core Web API getting null value for parameters class object

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

[image]

When I call the post employee web API method from my MVC controller, it's getting only null of this API employee object null value parameter.

But the `get` method is working fine.

This is the code for my Web API methods:

```
public ActionResult PostEmployee([FromRoute] Employee employee)
{
    _context.Employees.Add(employee);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Conflict();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync(IFormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.Eno = Convert.ToInt16(collection["Eno"].ToString());
        employee.Ename = collection["Ename"].ToString();
        employee.Address = collection["Address"].ToString();
            
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            string endpoint = apiBaseUrl + "Employees/PostEmployee";

            using (var Response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, content))
            {
                if (Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your route to the `PostEmployee()` action method look like? Why do you want to do model binding (i.e. complex types) from the _route_?

Comment: in my web api model class object eno was string type but was passed as int so that null value passed to web api.
 sorry by mistake every thing looks fine now

Comment: I can't understand a single word of that.

Comment: Hi codecaster how to simplify  that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo to pass employee data to PostEmployee with `[FromRoute]`:

Employee:

```
public class Employee {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

action:

```
[HttpGet("PostEmployee/{Id}/{Name}")]
public ActionResult PostEmployee([FromRoute] Employee employee)
{
    _context.Employees.Add(employee);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Conflict();
}
```

sample url:

```
.../PostEmployee/1/name1
```